# Lower bound on the roots of polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

To solve a problem almost identical to the one in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1007576/expected-number-of-rolls) I would like to locate the zeros of the function
$$
Q(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{m-1}(m-k)z^k = \frac{m - (m+1)z + z^{m+1}}{{(z-1)}^2}
$$
where $m$ is a positive integer.
In particular, I want to show that $Q(z)=0 \implies |z|>R$ for some $R \geq 1$.

- Based on computer solutions it seems that the statement holds at least for $R=\frac{m+1}{m}$, perhaps even $R=\frac{m+2}{m}$, so I have mostly worked with discs of such radii while trying to prove the statement.
- I have tried using Rouché's theorem, but so far it has only given me bounds with $R<1$.
- Inspired by plots of the roots I considered the equation $Q(z-c)=0$ shifting the roots by some real number $c$ but it didn't seem to help.
- A possibly related observation that I have not proven is that the roots of $Q(z)$ sum up to $-2$.

Comment: The roots of $Q(z)$ sums up to 0, not $-2$

Comment: @Exodd Indeed, the roots of the numerator $m - (m+1)z + z^{m+1}$ do sum up to 0 but $Q(z)$ has the root of multiplicity 2 at $z=1$ removed. Are you sure you're not including that one?

Comment: Doesn't you last comment prove that the roots add up to $-2$?

Comment: @nukelawe you are right, they sum up to $-2$, my bad

Comment: Enestrom kakeya theorem shows that one can take $R$ for which $m-k>(m-k+1)R,  k=0,..., m-2$ so $m/(m-1)$ would do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following theorem is due to Eneström (1893):

THEOREM. *Let $p_n(z) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_iz^i$ be a polynomial with positive real coefficients ($a_i>0$ for all $0\le i \le n$).
Then all the zeros of $p_n(z)$ are contained in the annulus*
$$\alpha\le |z|\le \beta,
$$
*where*
$$
\alpha=\min_{0\le i<n}\frac{a_i}{a_{i+1}};\quad \beta=\max_{0\le i<n}\frac{a_i}{a_{i+1}}.
$$

Apply this to  your polynomial in its original form.

> $$\alpha=\frac{m}{m-1};\quad\beta=2.$$